# Sum of Tree Leaves using Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, lambda, binary-tree

I'm trying to return the sum of values in its left leaves. My trees are defined with this interface

```py
class Tree(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.value = x
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
```

I am confused as to how/why this lambda function accomplishes this task. Could someone explain what the lambda function is checking for?

```py
leftLeavesSum=g=lambda t,f=0:t and f*t.value*(t.left==t.right)+g(t.left,1)+g(t.right) or 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is going to be long. Not because it's complicated, but because I wanted to explain things as simple as I can.

So, let's divide the answer into three parts:

1. How does this `lambda` function work?
2. Let's try out an example to see if it does its job
3. How to fix any problems if found

### First Part

How does this `lambda` function work? The best way to know that is to divide this whole `lambda` into simple `if..else` conditions like so which hopefully will be self-explanatory:

```
def g(t, f=0):
    if t:                               #checks if t is not None
        sum_left_branch = g(t.left,1)   #gets the sum of left branch
        sum_right_branch = g(t.right)   #gets the sum of right branch
        is_leaf_node = t.left==t.right  #1 if t is a leaf node (has no children)
        return (f*t.value)*is_leaf_node + sum_left_branch + sum_right_branch
    else:
        return 0
```

This function uses `f` to filter values. As you can see, `f` is zero when it's used with `t.right` which makes the value of `(f*t.value)*is_leaf_node` of the right branch always zero.

### Second part:

In the following code, I'm going to create a simple tree on the following form and see if this function works as it should be:

```
#    __1
#   /   \
#  3     2
# / \
#4   5

parent = Tree(1)
brother = Tree(2)
me = Tree(3)
child1 = Tree(4)
child2 = Tree(5)
# set connections
parent.left = me
parent.right = brother
me.left = child1
me.right = child2
```

Now, let's run the function over the `parent`:

```
leftLeavesSum(parent)  #4
```

Which is the value of leftmost leaf node `child1 = Tree(4)`. According to your question, you want the sum of all leaves on the left branch. So, the value should be `7` if you didn't count the `root` and `8` if you did.

So, I think this function doesn't work properly; which leads us to the third part

### Third part

The following is the right implementation to this function (in my opinion) with the minimum amount of change:

```
def g(t, f=0):
    if t is not None:
        sum_left_branch = g(t.left,1)
        return (f*t.value) + sum_left_branch
    return 0
```

Let's try this function with the same `Tree` as before:

```
# exclude the root
g(parent)    #7

# include the root
g(parent, 1) #8
```

Comment: Is it more efficient or preferred to use a lambda function instead of a fully defined function (as shown in the first part)?

Comment: they are the same thing.